# Получить значение из базы данных по _id, значение которого получено из предыдущей активити

Tags: android, база-данных

Исходные: есть база данных, в ней четыре столбца

```
COLUMN_ID = "_id";
COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
COLUMN_CHECK = "Check";
```

Из предыдущей активности в текущую отправляется значение

```
intent.putExtra("head", 41);
```

Задача такая:
1. получить из это значение в текущей активности
2. из базы достать значение `Check` (оно или `1` или `0`) для `_id`  равным полученному значению
Использовать значение `Check`

Использую такой код:

```
Intent position = getIntent();
        int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        positionValue = Integer.parseInt("_id");
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(positionValue)};
        db = sqlHelper.open();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int check = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_CHECK"));

            if (check == 0) {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_off));
            }
            if (check == 1) {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_on));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Приложение вылетает с ошибкой

Comment: С какой ошибкой вылетает

Comment: Что это, как отправляется, как получается, RecyclerView или TextView, мало информации как по мне. Вы так то отправляете значение 41

Comment: кнопкой switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn41:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Read.class);
                intent.putExtra("head", 41);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

Comment: @Романыч простите. тольео так могу ошибку показать. Эмулятор отвалился, отлаживаю на телефоне  https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9l69mubmznxghb/img_20191205_234807.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Надо сделать для работы модель данных, POJO  и делать интент item.get_id()

Comment: int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        positionValue = Integer.parseInt("_id");   тут хаос творится.

Comment: а как присвоить _id значение, которое я получаю из предыдущей активности?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101844/discussion-between--and-ru38irk).

Comment: не могу в чат зайти

Comment: @Романыч все равно не получается как вы написали...